# Error Reading unicode word from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I'm new to python, I have a trouble reading data from mysql. Here in mysql, my table stores destination:

```
    |id  | Destination|
    |1   |Hà Nội      |
    |2   |Hồ Chí Minh |
```

...
but when I read it from python its return this: ' u\'H\xe0 N\u1ed9i\'' for Hà Nội. Is there any way to convert it back to original string: 'Hà Nội'
here is my code to open connection and select data:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mySQLConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost',database='traveltrend',charset='utf8',use_unicode=True)
    self.cursor = self.mySQLConnection.cursor(buffered=True)

 def getDest(self):
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT ID, ThanhPho FROM diadiem ")
    row = self.cursor.fetchone()
    listDest={}
    while row is not None:
        request = str(row)
        request = request.strip('()')
        request = request.split(',')
        encoding = "utf-8"
        on_error = "replace"
        place= request[1].encode(encoding,on_error)
```

Comment: Can you post the query that you have used to create the table?

Comment: I used php my admin to create the table, but here is the sql code generated
        CREATE TABLE `destination` (
            `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `ThanhPho` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 
             utf8_vietnamese_ci NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci;
@arun

Answer (score 0):

I connect with MySQLdb package. I read from MySQL with unicode characters and this worked for me.

```
from MySQLdb import connect
connection = connect(user='root', passwd='', host='localhost',db='traveltrend',use_unicode=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got an errror when trying to do your way: TypeError: 'use_unicode' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Works for me with MySQL-python==1.2.5. Which version do you use?